# Keyframes animation doesn't work after refresh

Tags: html, css

I have simple keyframes animation and it works only one after saving changes in CSS file (I use VSCode and his Live Server). But after refreshing page or deploying to github pages it doesn't work. Tried to add -webkit-, but nothing changed.

Animation with Keyframes should start after classList.toggle('visible') in js file.
My hidden-nav becomes visible anyway, but keyframes works only first time.

Can anyone suggest anything please? 
I'm beginner

```
<ul class="hidden-nav">
  <li><a href="#skills" class="nav-link">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Video</a></li>
  <li><a href="#price" class="nav-link">Price</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contacts" class="nav-link">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
.hidden-nav {
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 1000px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    right: -120px;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(40%, 0, 0);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "toggle" function you where using remove a token from the list, but i think you need to add it. Am i wrong?

I made something like this and it works after 2 seconds delay.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>Test</title>
<style>
    .hidden-nav {
        display: none;
        width: 500px;
        height: 1000px;
        padding-top: 100px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: black;
        right: -120px;
        top: -20px;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .visible {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in both;
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translate3d(40%, 0, 0);
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="toShow" class="hidden-nav">
        <li><a href="#skills" class="nav-link">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#video" class="nav-link">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#price" class="nav-link">Price</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacts" class="nav-link">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script>
    setInterval(() => {
        document.getElementById('toShow').classList.add('visible');
    }, 2000);
</script>
</html>
```